# Problems on retrieving object on a JSP using ValueStack

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, taglib, ognl

I put an object in the Struts2's `ValueStack` inside the intercept method of my interceptor using this code:

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation)
    ValueStack vS = invocation.getStack();
    vS.set("mainViewComponent", new MainViewComponent());
    ...
}
```

and I try to retrieve it on the jsp using this code

```
<s:property value="#mainViewComponent.contextPath" />
```

but this exception is thrown

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: JSPException including path '/_common/layout/fragments/httpHeader.jsp'.
at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:61) [:1.0.1]
at org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.JspRequest.doInclude(JspRequest.java:125) [:1.0.1]
at org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractViewRequest.dispatch(AbstractViewRequest.java:47) [:1.0.1]
at org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:45) [:1.0.1]
at org.apache.tiles.request.render.ChainedDelegateRenderer.render(ChainedDelegateRenderer.java:68) [:1.0.1]
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259) [:3.0.1]
at org.apache.tiles.TilesContainerWrapper.render(TilesContainerWrapper.java:108) [:3.0.1]
at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:188) [:3.0.1]
at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.execute(InsertAttributeModel.java:132) [:3.0.1]
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:299) [:3.0.1]
at org.apache.jsp._005fcommon.layout.base_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f0(base_jsp.java:161)
at org.apache.jsp._005fcommon.layout.base_jsp._jspService(base_jsp.java:72)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [:6.1.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [:6.1.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:734) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:541) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:479) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:407) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:265) [:1.0.1]
... 88 more
Caused by: source is null for getProperty(null, "contextPath") - Class: ognl.OgnlRuntime
File: OgnlRuntime.java
Method: getProperty
Line: 2310 - ognl/OgnlRuntime.java:2310:-1
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.handleOgnlException(OgnlValueStack.java:331) [:2.3.14.2]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.findValue(OgnlValueStack.java:309) [:2.3.14.2]
at org.apache.struts2.components.Property.start(Property.java:159) [:2.3.14.2]
at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:53) [:2.3.14.2]
at org.apache.jsp._005fcommon.layout.fragments.httpHeader_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fproperty_005f0(httpHeader_jsp.java:118)
at org.apache.jsp._005fcommon.layout.fragments.httpHeader_jsp._jspService(httpHeader_jsp.java:70)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [:6.1.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [:6.1.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:734) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:639) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:576) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:650) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:644) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.JspRequest.doInclude(JspRequest.java:123) [:1.0.1]
... 111 more
Caused by: ognl.OgnlException: source is null for getProperty(null, "contextPath")
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2310) [:]
at ognl.ASTProperty.getValueBody(ASTProperty.java:114) [:]
at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212) [:]
at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258) [:]
at ognl.ASTChain.getValueBody(ASTChain.java:141) [:]
at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212) [:]
at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258) [:]
at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494) [:]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.getValue(OgnlUtil.java:255) [:2.3.14.2]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.getValue(OgnlValueStack.java:356) [:2.3.14.2]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.tryFindValue(OgnlValueStack.java:345) [:2.3.14.2]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.tryFindValueWhenExpressionIsNotNull(OgnlValueStack.java:321) [:2.3.14.2]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.findValue(OgnlValueStack.java:307) [:2.3.14.2]
... 130 more
```

Someone could understand where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JSP you have included the header fragment, but the URL used to get the resource isn't working because it contains an OGNL expression that unable to evaluate, because it references to the `null` object.

Now I see you posted ho do you retrieve the URL

```
<s:property value="#mainViewComponent.contextPath" />
```

And error is that `#mainViewComponent` referenced the `ActionContext` property which is `null` because you didn't put the object to it, but you put it in the `valueStack` so should get

```
<s:property value="mainViewComponent.contextPath" />
```

Comment: I put this code for debug
`<%
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStack vS = 
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack();
 fi.fpf.base.mvc.FPFMainViewComponent mVC = (fi.fpf.base.mvc.FPFMainViewComponent)vS.findValue("mainViewComponent");
 mVC.getClass();
    %>`
and the mVC variable is valorized. I don't understand

Comment: @RobertoGentili In the S2 framework `#` is used to reference `ActionContext` objects, not objects from the `valueStack`.